# visual studio 2017 STL visualizer fails for one std::map<MyIntrusivePtr, std::tuple<....> >

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

All visual studio watch windows is displaying is:

```
std::_Tree<std::_TMap_traits<.....
```

All other data displays fine -- using the same or similar data.

Here is the header:

```
typedef std::set<expression::ptr> expressionSet;
//pairOfExpression2Usage m_sBool;
typedef boost::flyweights::flyweight<
    expressionSet,
    boost::flyweights::set_factory<>,
    boost::flyweights::refcounted
> expressionSetFW;
typedef std::pair<expressionSetFW, expressionSetFW> pairOfExpressionSetFW;
    // these are or-ed together
struct comparePairOfExpressionSetFW
{   bool operator()(
        const pairOfExpressionSetFW &_r0,
        const pairOfExpressionSetFW&_r1) const;
};
typedef std::set<
    pairOfExpressionSetFW,
    comparePairOfExpressionSetFW
> setOfPairOfExpressionSet;
struct compareSetOfPairOfExpressionSet
{   bool operator()(
        const setOfPairOfExpressionSet &_r0,
        const setOfPairOfExpressionSet&_r1) const;
};
typedef boost::flyweights::flyweight<
    setOfPairOfExpressionSet,
    boost::flyweights::set_factory<compareSetOfPairOfExpressionSet>,
    boost::flyweights::refcounted
> setOfPairOfExpressionSetFW;
typedef std::tuple<std::size_t, double, setOfPairOfExpressionSetFW> exprData;
typedef std::map<expression::ptr, exprData> expr2Data;
```

I already reinstalled the visualizers. Did

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Put the typedefs into global scope.
The curious thing is, that all other things (also using expression::ptr) as either index or data are displaying fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to hackaround this problem is to copy-convert the offensive

```
std::map<>
```

into a

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>
```

just for being able to look at it in the debugger.
The problem also happens with other std::map. I really would like to know, what is triggering this behavior.